# Fast of Dawud (a.s)

Tags: sunnah

As Salamu Alaikum,

I couldn't get a clear answer by searching on the web, the fast of Dawud (a.s) which is to fast every other day. Does it Starts from Fajr to Maghrib like a regular fast or does it starts at Maghrib till the next Maghrib. I can't seem find a clear answer and i don't know where did i get the second option.

There seems to be a lot more information about how it is not sinful to fast on a Friday if you do the fast of Dawud (a.s) than how the actual fast is performed or if carries a different law than the fasting of Nabi Muhammad (saws).

> So judge between them by what Allaah has revealed and do not follow
>   their inclinations away from what has come to you of the truth. To
>   each of you We prescribed a law and a method. Had Allaah willed, He
>   would have made you one nation [united in religion], but [He intended]
>   to test you in what He has given you; so race to [all that is] good.
>   To Allaah is your return all together, and He will [then] inform you
>   concerning that over which you used to differ.
>
> [Quran 5:48]
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> Allah's Apostle said, "Both in this world and in the Hereafter, I am
>   the nearest of all the people to Jesus, the son of Mary. The prophets
>   are paternal brothers; their mothers are different, but their religion
>   is one." Sahih-Volume 4, Book 55, Number 652

If someone can help it will be gladly appreciated.

Jazak'Allah Khair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alaikum as Salam,

Allah tells us when to fast in Surah al-Baqara 2:187 =

> **"...And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn becomes distinct to you from the black thread. Then complete the fast until the sunset..."**

The fasting Allah has given to us is the fasting from dawn to sunset.  There's no other fast we can do at any other time.

The fasting of Prophet Dawud was, he would fast for one day and skip one day as reported in the hadith coming from 'Abdullah bin 'Amr from the Prophet Mohammed.

The hadith forbidding to fast on Fridays is when someone fasts only that day and no other day.  Prophet Said,

> لاَ يَصُمْ أَحَدُكُمْ يَوْمَ الْجُمُعَةِ إِلاَّ أَنْ يَصُومَ قَبْلَهُ أَوْ يَصُومَ بَعْدَهُ
>   **"No among you should fast on day of Friday, but only that he fasts before it and after it."**

Therefore, if you fast one day and leave the next day, you will still be fasting either one day before Friday or one day after.

But to be safe, it's best to fast a day before Friday and a day after, three days in a row. Because the prohibition is stronger than the recommendation.

Allaho Alim.

Comment: I made it explicit that i'm not searching for this answer since its already all over the web. I'm asking if the fasting is made on the same pattern ie ( fajr to maghrib ) or does it hold a different pattern in of itself.

Comment: Read the beginning of my post.  You have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correction, fast of Dawud is every other day, so in this form of fast, its permitted to fast on Friday, cause one is not intentionally singling out Friday.